# How to get usable Connection String from IQueryable object that was created using .Net Entities Query

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, ado.net, connection-string, iqueryable

Under **usable** I mean string that I can use to connect to database with `SqlConection` and read data using `ExecuteReader`.

String that I get from `IQueryable.Context.Connection.ConnectionString` contains `"name=MyConnectionAlias"`.

What I need is value of `provider connection string` attribute that is defined for `MyConnectionAlias` in `connectionStrings` section of `config` file.

That value usually contains `Data Source=MyDbServer;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Intergrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
((System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)((ObjectQuery)IQueryable).Context.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString
```